# SQLite: Get week number from date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

How can I get week number from date, in SQL there is a function: Datepart(GetDate()) and this return the number of week. How can I get this in SQLite?

Comment: How is this question related to java and android?

Comment: It’s very broad. What did your search bring up? In what way was it insufficient or failed?

Comment: [SQL As Understood By SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) mentions week of year. See if you can use it. There is also the possibility of getting the week number in Java instead, of course.

Comment: Do you want to get Week number like this date belongs to 15th week of the year using java? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Define “week number”. Week # 1 contains January 1? Contains first occurrence of a specific day-of-week? First complete week made of only days from the new year? Standard [ISO 8601 week](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)? And search Stack Overflow before posting. This issue has been asked and answered many times already.

Comment: No,  contrary to your first sentence, I do not believe “DatePart” is standard SQL. It is a function in Microsoft SQL Server. Postgres, which closely follows the standard, has a `date_part` function.

Comment: Related: [SQLite return wrong week number for 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082584/sqlite-return-wrong-week-number-for-2013)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the **`strftime`** function with the format string (1st parameter) as **`%W`**

as per [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

#### Example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS getweek;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS getweek (mydate TEXT);
INSERT INTO getweek VALUES ('2018-01-01'),('2018-02-01'),('2018-03-01');
SELECT *, strftime('%W',mydate) AS weekofyear FROM getweek;
```

Which results in :-

[image]

**Note** The date has to be in one of the recognised date/time formats (e.g. 2018/03/01 would result in null as the date is not in recognised format). See the **Time Strings** section in the link above for the recognised formats.

Comment: Unfortunately that documentation does not explain what definition of week is used by that function. It might be [standard ISO 8601 week](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Is there any definitive documentation you can link/quote in your Answer?

Comment: It does not conform to the ISO standard. The sqlite documentation mentions in a table that `%W` corresponds to "week of year: 00-53". But ISO weeks run from 1-53. Sqlite seems to follow the Ruby convention. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084840/1150961 for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appropriate format specifier with `strftime()`.

See [SQLite Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for details.